# python docx delete table from document

Tags: python-docx

I want to remove some tables from a document based on the contents of the upper left cell.

I tried:

```
allTables = document.tables
for activeTable in allTables:
    if activeTable.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].text == 'some text':
        allTables.remove(activeTable)
```

I expected to have removed all tables containing 'some text' in cell(0,0), but they are still in the document.

The process enters the line with "allTables.remove(activeTable)" as expected:      `indexToDelete = allTables.index(activeTable)`within the if statement gives the tables, I'm looking for.

The message is "Process finished with exit code 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your test `if activeTable...text == 'some text'` is not succeeding for any of the tables. In that case, the `.remove()` call is never executed but the script still returns an exit code of `0` (success).

Start by validating your test, maybe something like:

```
for table in document.tables:
    print("'%s'" % table.cell(0, 0).paragraphs[0].text)
```

and make sure the paragraph text is what you think it is. This should print out something like:

```
'some text but also some other text'
...
```

Once you have that determined, you may want to test on something other than the entire string, perhaps using `.startswith()`:

```
text = table.cell(0, 0).paragraphs[0].text
if text.startswith('some text'):
    print('found one')
```

Once you have that working you can move on to the next problem.

Comment: This is not the problem.  The code   `for activeTable in allTables:  
    if activeTable.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].text == 'some text':
        indexOfTableToDelete = allTables.index(activeTable)  
        print("Table to delete: ", 1+ indexOfTableToDelete)  
        del allTables[indexOfTableToDelete]  
`

Comment: Sorry. my comment was sent before it was finished.  The code   `for activeTable in allTables:  
    if activeTable.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].text == 'some text':
        indexOfTableToDelete = allTables.index(activeTable)  
        print("Table to delete: ", 1+ indexOfTableToDelete)  
        del allTables[indexOfTableToDelete]  
` prints:  Table to delete:  3  
Table to delete:  8  
Table to delete:  10  Those are the tables, that I'm lookoing for.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see what's happening now. You're removing the table from the list that `document.tables` returns (`allTables`) but that doesn't remove the table from the underlying XML. Try `activeTable._element.getparent().remove(activeTable._element)` instead.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution. I thought that allTables and document.tables are two names of the same object. But they are two different objects.

Comment: The `Table._element` objects will be the same in all instances (one for each table). But the `Table` object itself is just a proxy object (wrapper) around the element and the "tables" object is simply a list. So each time you call `Document.tables` you get a new one (`.tables` is a property, so the result you get is the return value of a method, not a "static" attribute of the document). Don't neglect to accept this answer. That's how you "pay" for someone taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The solution is:

```
allTables = document.tables

for activeTable in allTables:
    if activeTable.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].text == 'some text':
        activeTable._element.getparent().remove(activeTable._element)
```

Thanks to scanny.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```py
from docx import Document

document = Document('YOUR_DOCX')

def Delete_table(table):
        document.tables[table]._element.getparent().remove(document.tables[table]._element)

Delete_table(0)

document.save('OUT.docx')
```